# How to setup a long running spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have following scenario in my project;

1. I will continue to get a stream of data from a source
2. I need to calculate mean and variance for a key every minute
3. After minute is over I should restart fresh computing the values for new minute

Example:

**10:00:00 computation and output**

10:00:00 key =1 , mean = 10 , variance =2

10:00:00 key =N , mean = 10 , variance =2

**10:00:01 computation and output**

10:00:00 key =1 , mean = 11 , variance =2

10:00:00 key =N , mean = 12 , variance =2

**10:00:01 data has no dependency with 10:00:00**

How to setup such jobs in a single java spark streaming application.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options: -

**First** - You can setup Batch Duration as 60 Seconds then the data received from the stream can be used to calculate the Mean and Variance.

**Second** - You can Leverage `DStream.window` function for example see the below pseudo code: -

```
val streamCtx = new StreamingContext(sparkCtx, Seconds(10))
//Assuming that you are using Flume and creating a Polling Stream
val flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(streamCtx, <Array[InetSocketAddress]>, <StorageLevel>, 1000, 1)
val windowStream = flumeStream.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(60))
//Now here process windowStream and calculate means and variance of each Key.
```

for more info refer to [DStream API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)